# How to take parameters from Axios call to a Delete generic view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm making a DELETE request through an axios call like this:

```
unfollow(unFollowId) {
  var payload = {
    follower_id: this.user.id,
    followed_id: unFollowId
  };
  axios
    .delete("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tweets/follow/", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      data: { payload }
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
}
```

**Views.py** The print function is me testing how I can just make sure the parameters are being read properly.

```
class Followers(generics.CreateAPIView, mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = FollowerSerializer

    def get(self, request, follower_id=None):
        if follower_id != None:
            followers = Follower.objects.filter(follower_id=follower_id)
        else:
            followers = Follower.objects.all()
        data = FollowerSerializer(followers, many=True).data
        return Response(data)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.queryset())
        # unfollow = Follower.objects.filter(
        #     follower_id=follower_id, followed_id=followed_id)
        # unfollow.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def post(self, request):
        return self.create(request)
```

I've removed the Delete mixin because I'm not sure which I'm supposed to use and how to use it to be able to read parameters.

Comment: Is your `delete` method being called successfully? If so, you should access `request.POST` to get the payload from your axios request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For post

```
    params = request.data
    p = params.get('yourkey')
 or 
   p = request.data.get('yourkey')
```

To get

```
p = self.request.query_params.get('yourkey')
```